# Formatting citations to the literature on MathOverflow

Tags: discussion, user-interface, citations

We'd like to make it easier to cite articles from the literature, on MathOverflow.

> I propose adding a single button to the edit toolbar while writing posts, which will pop up a search dialog, allow the user to select a result, and then insert a nicely formatted link to the paper back into the edit box.

The button would appear next to the current four icons for inserting hyperlinks, blockquotes, preformatted text, and images. (We could insert this button ourselves, via our allowed javascript footer, but eventually we'd want SE to insert it natively.)

To get a sense of how the search dialog might work, please look at [this prototype](http://semorrison.github.io/citation-search/).
(Obviously this would need some polishing; suggestions for improvements welcome.)

Once a search result has been selected, I propose inserting into the edit box something like:

```
<span class="citation" authors="Sendak, Maureen and Geisel, Theresa" mrnumber="MR1234567"
      cite="J. Unexpected Results 17 (2015), no. 1, 17-29">
  <a href="http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/2222">A mathematics paper</a>
</span>
```

which will render simply as the hyperlink [A mathematics paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/2222). The hyperlink should be the 'best available URL', e.g. the DOI resolution address, a direct link to the published version, or the link to the corresponding record on MathSciNet.

I would like to include the extra `<span>` tag around the actual hyperlink for several reasons:

1. it makes the extra citation data available, in case the user wants to also show the authors or journal reference in the text,
2. it allows us to render citation links differently via the CSS selector `.citation` if desired,
3. it allows us to programmatically detect and reformat citation links after the fact, if desired (e.g. to provide links to your local library's resolver).

There are a number of things we'll need to do:

- verify we really can add a button to the edit interface
- pick a 'backend' for the search dialog (the prototype above is a hack; it would be nice to run off MathSciNet or Zentralblatt, etc, but this may require a lot of coordination)
- design and build the search dialog
- beta test with some users

Comment: I recall similar discussions on meta.MSE,

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have looked at the questions that are tagged [citation](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation), but I did not find which one you have in mind. The only thing I recall, which is related to this, is [DOI support for hyperlinks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104031/doi-support-for-hyperlinks) - a [meta-tag:feature-request] by Willie Wong on meta.SO.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, the DOI feature was born from a discussion, and my adamant refusal to open an account on meta.SO, leading Willie to post this request. (It was before the days that it was established that feature requests can be made on any meta.) I should also point out that the situation here is different, because MO is allowed to inject non-malicious scripts into the page, so we can do it independently.

Comment: @quid: Oh, it might be the case that I was thinking about this thread. (Scott, note how you claimed to be uninterested in implementing this yourself. :-))

Comment: @AsafKaragila (Sorry I deleted comment as I were to add something. Yes I think this could be it, see one of your later comments)  There is a discussion on tea started  also mentioning some to be started discussion on meta.math.SE see http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1147/doi-feature/ Yet in a comment to this later related  dicussion you only recall tea and meta.SO http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277/would-it-be-possible-to-use-something-like-wikipedias-templates-here

Comment: Thank you for the historical research! I'd forgotten so much (even though I'd been part of those conversations).

Comment: The 'hack' search interface above already recognizes MR numbers, and could very easily be made to recognize arXiv identifiers too. I'm imagining that if you already have text selected when clicking the 'add citation' button, that will be pasted into the search. Thus one could simply type 'in the paper MR12345', highlight the MR12345, click the 'add citation' button, accept the first search result, and be on your way. This sounds really appealing to me!

Comment: I have a very similar feature request on MSO (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116397/add-explicit-support-for-citing-scientific-literature). Mine is a bit more focused on life sciences though.

Comment: By the way, the script is pretty awesome. I got a bit scared when "Iggy Pop" returned ten results. :-)

Comment: @MadScientist's request also suggests footnoting the full citation, which I think is a nice idea.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yes, as written it's intended as a very 'fast and loose' search. If some of your search queries don't match, it still returns the best matches for the others. Notice [iggy](http://semorrison.github.io/citation-search/?q=iggy) returns no results

Comment: Yeah, obviously the "Iggy Pop" search was to poke fun at this pretty cool tool. I also searched for several metal bands. Interestingly most of them (except obvious names like Death and Earth) returned nothing. [Abyssic Hate](http://semorrison.github.io/citation-search/?q=abyssic%20hate), on the other hand, had four results! :-)

Comment: It is definitely possible to add buttons to the edit window; for a nice example see [**MathJax buttons on the edit window**](http://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons) in stackapps.

Comment: [(Link to this question on meta.physics.se)](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5495/a-cite-this-paper-will-you-button).

Comment: I was going to comment here with links to the necessary javascript for extending the edit window, but @EmilioPisanty already posted it :p The code for adding buttons starts [here](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/MathJaxButtonsScript.js#L122)

Comment: @Emilio: Note that while it is always possible to use StackApps addons, MathOverflow enjoys the courtesy of injecting JS code into the page itself which may allow a uniform output regardless to the user's choice of StackApp preferences. SE may or may not extend the same courtesy to Physics.SE, Math.SE, CSTheory.SE, and Cross Validated. All whom I believe would benefit from this sort of code.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was vaguely aware of something of the sort. I thing it's getting ahead of the game; it's pointless to speculate about whether SE will include it or not (presumably they will, if we ask loudly enough), without having at least some sort of working prototype, or at least agreement over the specs for one.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, thanks for this. Someone (likely me) should adapt the example you linked to do what we want. If that looks okay we can arrange to inject it from the footer.

Comment: Old request for this feature in MSO, turned up by Shog9: [Add explicit support for citing scientific literature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116397/add-explicit-support-for-citing-scientific-literature).

Answer (score 21):

> We now have a prototype for inserting citations!

See it in action in this [video tutorial](http://youtu.be/hrCUjtepj7E).

It currently requires you to install a user script, and has only been tested on the Chrome browser.

To get started, open Chrome, and click on [this link](https://github.com/Manishearth/SE-CitationHelper/raw/stable/citationhelper.user.js) to download the user script. Once you've downloaded it, go to the "Window" menu in Chrome and select "Extensions". Drag and drop the downloaded user script file into the Extensions tab, and click "Add".

Now, visit MathOverflow and start asking a new question (or starting answering an existing question). You'll see at the top of the edit box there's a button labelled `\cite`. Click this, and a search dialog will pop up. (If you've selected text in the edit window, this will automatically be copied into the search dialog.) The search dialog accepts titles, authors, and citation data in any combination. You'll see one or more best matches, and often a preview of the PDF in the right pane. If you see what you want, select it in the left pane, and a nicely formatted citation will be inserted back in the edit box!

Here are some screenshots of the script in action.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make the citation link text more than just the title? I would prefer a more comprehensive link text, with authors, journal, year, etc. It is easy to delete this or simplify it, for those who don't want it, but a bit harder to add it in. Also, I guess the literature search doesn't seem to include the math arxiv?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, I think this can be arranged pretty easily. The search tool returns all this data, so it's just a matter of tweaking the javascript that inserts the link. I'll ask Manish to do this. I can include all the arxiv readily enough, but I'm going to wait on resolving another issue.

Comment: Another idea might be to make the article title the link, but to have the rest of the citation information such as author and journal etc. available inside the <cite> object as (unlinked) mere text.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins What do you think of [this](https://github.com/Manishearth/SE-CitationHelper/blob/master/citationhelper.user.js), for the linkification? (A quick way to test this for one page is to  disable the citation userscript in chrome://extensions and copy the code from the above link into the JS console; Ctrl-Shift-J) The entire block now inserts the citation, however you can click on a preview link and have the preview load inline.

Comment: @Manishearth, I am very sorry, but I evidently I am not capable of implementing your script properly. Perhaps you can just provide a sample output?

Comment: @joel [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlgk0.png). There's a chance I broke something yesterday (I linked you to the non-stable branch of the code which is not guaranteed to work), I'll have a look in a while. Thanks.

Comment: @Manishearth, looks great, if I understand what you are saying.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, I've just added some screenshots, showing how it works and the updated linking style.

Comment: We need to sort a few things out in the background, but hopefully this is going to be ready soon!

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly the kind of thing I had had in mind with my suggestion.

Comment: So when can we expect a FF script?

Comment: Great! Tested in Firefox and GreaseMonkey and seems to work (I needed to allow javascript from herakuapp.com). By the way can you add also [cstheory.se] to the list of the sites that the script works on?

Comment: @Kaveh: Is there anything particular that needs to be done in order to install this on FF+GM?

Comment: @Kaveh, the search tool is _very_ experimental at this point. Don't get too excited about using it on other sites yet.

Comment: @Asaf, no, I just clicked on the link to the script and installed it. @ Scott, OK. :)

Comment: Scott, I've just used the script (on MSE, though) for a live test. It worked out great, but I do have some minor remarks. Should I send you an email, or what?

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you do so, cc it to me, thanks :) (username at gmail)

Comment: @Manishearth: No offense, but I don't think so. I'm trying to minimize the exposure of my email to nonessential personnel. (If I hadn't already emailed with Scott, I wouldn't have suggested email to begin with, and I would have just found some other way instead.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, Manishearth has done all the user interface coding for this feature. I've done all the back-end stuff. Depending on what your remarks about about, cc'ing Manishearth may make good sense.

Comment: Who did the output formatting? Because my biggest complaint is that it should look like a citation in a paper: author, "title". journal, volume (year) pages. (My preference is that title and volume are in boldface and journal is italicized, but that's just me). @Manish

Comment: @AsafKaragila you can use a throwaway email :) So, the output formatting was arbitrarily chosen. Ideally Stack Exchange should generate that server side, but that's a long way off. The intention was a proof of concept, but I'll play with the formatting later today.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, the output formatting is my doing. Let's take it to email.

Comment: Scott, @Manishearth, bug report/feedback: the first thing is that it sometimes takes way longer for the page to complete loading. Sometimes when I click on show addition comments link it doesn't work correctly when the userscript is enabled. ps: should we post this kind of feedback as a new answer or a comment?

Comment: @Kaveh the best place to report issues is [here](https://github.com/Manishearth/SE-CitationHelper/issues), but pinging me here is fine too. (Somehow I missed this). I think Scott's backend is acting strange in this case. I'll try rehosting it this weekend if possible and look into it (no guarantees though, I'm not too familiar with the backend).

Comment: The backend is currently hosted on a free Heroku account. They shut down the instance if it's unused for an hour, after which the first usage incurs a ~20 second startup. It should be easy to host elsewhere; it's packaged as a git repository with a single startup script that sets everything up from scratch.

Comment: Eventually we might ask SE to host it. In the meantime we just need something that allows you to run a java process and listen for incoming connections on some port. I could run it on an Amazon EC2 instance easily enough, as I already run stuff there. I could probably also run it on http://katlas.org/, a server sitting under Dror Bar-Natan's desk in Toronto.

Comment: @Manishearth This extension no longer works for me in Chrome, since Chrome won't let me enable it, as it is not "from the Chrome store". Is there any way to get it working again? Can it be made available at the Chrome web store?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins There are some solutions to the problem [here](http://superuser.com/questions/767286/re-enable-extensions-not-coming-from-chrome-web-store-on-chrome-v35-with-enhan) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095006/enable-a-non-playstore-userscript-with-chrome-35-and-above). I shall try to publish this to the play store, maybe as an unlisted app, next week when I'm not travelling so much.

Comment: I'm working on getting this working 'live' (i.e. for everyone, without an extension), but it's a potentially  long process.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a very useful feature to me. I am not an expert on HTML and co; but wouldn't the `cite` element be more appropriate than a general `span` tag?

As far as I know, you can still use all the other attributes that you were already using. The benefit would be a more semantic markup, which is good for SEO, and for custom stylesheets of users (or say specific browsers).

You could still keep the `.citation` class, but it would even be less necessary. (Though I can imagine you want someway to distinguish between tags inserted by this button, and cite-tags inserted manually by users.)