# Formatting problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, markdown

In my answer to

[When is the closed unit ball in a smaller Banach space closed in a larger Banach space?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224231/when-is-the-closed-unit-ball-in-a-smaller-banach-space-closed-in-a-larger-banach)

I wrote the following:

> >
>   Edit: $Y=Z^*$ does not display correctly when it is in the body of the preceding paragraph.  It seems to be because there are two \^ * symbols in the same paragraph. What is the work around?  Adding single quotes does not completely fix the problem.
>   >

I have not previously encountered this one.

Comment: Using `\ast` instead of the symbol `*` should work (I did not try it though, as I was not sure what exactly would need to be changed). [Maybe some braces around the `\ast` are needed, as usual for 'longer' exponents, but I think in fact it should work without.]

Comment: The root-cause might be the same as on this recent report http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2596/braces-dont-render-in-preview That is for some reason the 'escaping' of certain characters on MO, at least for the preview, is broken. Strangely it seems not broken on meta.MO.

Comment: François fixed it using what you suggested, quid.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know; I am glad it worked.

Answer (score 8):

This had to do with the citation helper script - mostly with how I implemented the integration with the editor.

The fix is being deployed right now.