# Missing brackets in $\{x\}$ in drafts, not missing in the final question/product

Tags: feature-request, bug, mathjax, markdown-preview, latex

I am using the latest version of Firefox on Linux (bodhi linux) as well as Mac and Windows.

Some $\LaTeX$ is not typeset correctly in MathOverflow: whenever I type a set, like the singleton $\{x\}$, the curly braces $\{\}$ never show up in the draft or after clicking "review your post" -- but they do in whenever I am finished editing and "release" the post into the wild (by clicking "Post your question" for example).

Curiously, this problem does not occur on meta.MathOverflow, but on many other sites of the stackexchange universe, like cstheory, stats, and cs.

Does anyone else have this problem or know its source or best: know how to fix it?

Comment: Is this basically the same question as: [Braces are not rendered in MathJax in the preview of a question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5163) and [Escaped braces do not render in post preview](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31124)? (The second one is on [math.meta.se].)

Comment: Thank you @MartinSleziak for the chat that you sent me, encouraging me to un-delete this question. I just did that. (I wasn't able to reply to your chat post, so I write here.)

Comment: As I [mentioned in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2024/2/15), this problem seems to be here for a long time, so a new bug report might be useful - as a reminder; despite the fact that there are similar older posts.
In the meantime I found also this post on [meta.se]: [MathJax escape sequences don't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387653). The poster of that question says that for them everything worked find in Edge - for me, the bug manifests both in Google Chrome and in Microsoft Edge.