# Request for help with javascript for the citation search feature

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, citation-helper

I would like to switch over the [citation helper](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2583/new-feature-citation-helper) from the current kludged together back-end based on MathSciNet data, to an officially supported back-end (very kindly!) provided by Zentralblatt.

We'll need to rewrite a small amount of javascript for this to happen. If someone (ideally who knows javascript, and ideally who knows how to hack the existing javascript served on a page, so the new code can be tested before deployment) would like to help, please let me know.

The problem is simple to describe:

> We need to modify the code currently served via http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/third-party/citation-helper.js?v=2, so that instead of retrieving results from, https://ec2.mathoverflow.org/cite?q=, it retrieves results from https://zbmath.org/citationmatching/mathoverflow?q=, and appropriately parses the JSON.

It's mostly just a matter of working out how the JSON structure has changed, and emitting appropriate HTML based on that. The HTML should be basically the same as what we already produce, but we should also include the Zbl identifier, linked directly to the corresponding Zbl page. The title of the article itself should be a hyperlink to the first "link" result.

Comment: So it's really just modifying `getCitationHtml`to match the JSON data from ZBL?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It should be quite straightforward.

Comment: I gave it my mediocre shot.

Comment: I've marked this as "status-planned", as the modified code is now off to Stack Exchange for review, and hopefully deployment not far down the track.

Comment: I think now it's as good a time as any to put [tag:status-completed] on this post.

Answer (score 7):

As an example, the first result [here](https://zbmath.org/citationmatching/mathoverflow?q=Joan%20Bagaria%20and%20Menachem%20Magidor,%20On%20%CF%891-strongly%20compact%20cardinals,%20J.%20Symb.%20Log.%2079%20(2014),%20no.%201,%20266--278.) contains the JSON

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "pagination": "266-278", 
      "links": [
        "http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/jsl.2013.12"
      ], 
      "title": "On $\\omega_1$-strongly compact cardinals", 
      "year": "2014", 
      "source": "J. Symb. Log. 79, No. 1, 266-278 (2014).", 
      "score": 3.316698, 
      "zbl_id": "1337.03076", 
      "authors": "Bagaria, Joan; Magidor, Menachem"
    },
    ...
}
```

which should render as something like

> *Bagaria, Joan; Magidor, Menachem*,  [**On $\omega_1$-strongly compact cardinals**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/jsl.2013.12), J. Symb. Log. 79, No. 1, 266-278 (2014). [Zbl 1337.03076](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1337.03076)

Comment: Is there any chance to get the "source" field break down to journal/volume/number/pages/year? You know, like a proper .bib citation?

Comment: I'll ask, but my contact at Zentralblatt is now on holidays.

Comment: Scott, being unfamiliar with the Christian world's holidays. When do these holidays end usually? Do we have to wait until next year? That's insane, it's an entire year! :-)

Comment: He said he'll back be mid-January.

Comment: Is next week "mid-January"?

Comment: Ok, "mid-January" is now. :-) Could you explain why it would be better to break the source field down into components? Fabian at Zentralblatt says it might be possible, but I'm hesitant to ask him to do this work without good motivation.

Comment: Well, it's nicer to have a better control over the formatting of the output. I figured it must be a few lines of code (instead of collecting journal/volume/number/pages/year into one field, just return them separately). If it's a lot of work, I guess we can work with what we have.

Comment: We've decided it's too much work.

Comment: Oh well. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
function getCitationHtml(json) {
    var cite = $('<cite>').attr('authors', json.authors)
              .append('_' + json.authors + '_, ')
              .append('[**' + json.title + '**](' + encodeURI(json.links.length > 0 ? json.links[0] : '') + '), ')
              .append(json.source + ' [Zbl' + json.zbl_id + '](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:' + json.zbl_id + ')')
              .append('.');

    var citeContainer = $('<span></span>').append(cite).html();

    return citeContainer;
    }
```

Comment: I have never worked with Jason, so I have no idea if this is even valid. Do let me know, though.

Comment: First --- we're going to have to work out how to test this. Can someone who knows how to do this show us how to modify in place the javascript coming from SE?

Comment: Second, I see some problems. 
1) `json.links` is an array, possibly empty. If it is non-empty, we want to use the first entry as the URL. If it is empty we don't want to hyperlink the title. 
2) There is no longer a `json.citation_markdown` field.

Comment: (Thanks, of course, for making a start!)

Comment: I guess we can change this using Developer Tools to change an instance of the running code and check. I'll give it a shot in a little bit.

Comment: Also, I think that in answers if you use an empty link, it just produces a text.

Comment: I added a test for `json.links` being empty; I think the previous code would have linked to "undefined".

Comment: We are now waiting on Zentralblatt adding an `Allow-Access-Control-Origin` header, so that we can test this code. No update expected until mid-January.

Comment: Any news on the header issue?

Comment: The headers are all fixed.  For now it allows all cross domain requests.

Answer (score 3):

We will also need to modify the `fetchCallback` function from http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/third-party/citation-helper.js?v=2.

This is the current content of that function, which we can "edit in place" to update.

```
// Callback to run when search completes.
function fetchCallback(response) {
  // Here's an example of what the 'response' argument might contain.
  // response = {
  //  "results": [
  //    {
  //      "pagination": "2586-2620", 
  //      "links": [
  //        "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jfa.2014.12.018", 
  //        "http://www.arxiv.org/abs/1406.4766"
  //      ], 
  //      "title": "Free transport for finite depth subfactor planar algebras", 
  //      "year": "2015", 
  //      "source": "", 
  //      "score": 2.15747, 
  //      "zbl_id": "06435710", 
  //      "authors": "Nelson, Brent"
  //    }, 
  //    {
  //      "pagination": "183-214", 
  //      "links": [
  //        "http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1021296230310"
  //      ], 
  //      "title": "Exchange relation planar algebras", 
  //      "year": "2002", 
  //      "source": "Geom. Dedicata 95, 183-214 (2002).", 
  //      "score": 2.15747,   
  //      "zbl_id": "1022.46039", 
  //      "authors": "Landau, Zeph A."
  //    }
  //  ]
  // }        
        var html = $('<div class="list">');
        for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
            var result = response.results[i];
            var zbl = 'https://zbmath.org/?q=an:' + result.zbl_id;

            var link = result.links.length > 0 ? result.links[0] : '';
            var arxiv = '';
            for (var j = 0; j < result.links.length; j++) {
                     arxiv = result.links[j].includes("arxiv") ? result.links[j] : arxiv;
                }
            var authors = sanitizeForDisplay(result.authors);
            var title = sanitizeForDisplay(result.title);
            var citationHtml = sanitizeForDisplay(result.source);

            var result = $('<div class="item" style="float:none;padding:5px">')
                .html($('<div class = "summary post-link" style="float:none;width:auto;font-weight:bold;">')
                    .text(title))
                .append('<br/>')
                .append($('<span class="body-summary" style="float:none"></span>')
                    .append(authors + '<br/>' + citationHtml + '<br/> Preview (opens in new tab): ')
                    .append(renderOptionalLink(link, 'article'))
                    .append(renderOptionalLink(zbl, 'zbmath'))
                    .append(renderOptionalLink(arxiv, 'arxiv'))
                )
                .click(loadResultCallback(link, result))
                .hover(function () { $(this).css('background-color', '#e6e6e6') }, function () { $(this).css('background-color', '#fff') });

            html.append(result);
            result.find('a').on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
        }
        $('#results').html('').append(html);
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, 'results']);
        $('#popup-cite .search-spinner').removeSpinner();
}
```

Comment: I've tried to do some editing. Of course we don't know how badly it will fail before we can test it properly. But I do think that having separate fields for the citation parts is crucial for getting properly formatted output. I'm not entirely sure about the `free` and `pdf` fields, though.

Comment: I probably messed it up, but I tried to add a code that checks if there is a link with `arxiv` substring, and in that case it adds it to the optional links.

Comment: Ah, good idea. Fixed [two problems](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/3060/revisions).

Comment: Wow, only one minor typo and one syntactic problem? Impressive.

Comment: You might want to test it before you push it, I have created a Stack Snippet [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288724/158100). I'm not sure what is in the pending edit but you need to remove `.citation` from this line `var result = response.results[i].citation;` otherwise it won't work. If you find Stack Snippets to cumbersome, consider a jsfiddle.

Comment: @rene: Of course there will be testing before we push the new code. But we need to wait for ZBL to fix some stuff, and maybe return "better json" (as you can find in the comments to the other answers on this page).