# Is the citation helper broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, citation-helper

For the last several days I've had no luck using the [citation helper](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2583/13653). Whenever I attempt to search for anything,  although a search seems to be ongoing even letting it sit for minutes doesn't produce any results.

[image: citation helper search]

(The dots below the search string cycle as though searching. Screenshot courtesy of Martin Sleziak; thanks.)

[I inquired if anyone else was having difficulty in the MathOverflow chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35709659#35709659), and so far 100% of the respondents have reported a similar issue. (Granted, so far there has only been one response.)

---

- According the the Chrome console, I get the following errors, `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` and `GET https://ec2.mathoverflow.org/cite?q=&_=########### net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`.
- According to the Microsoft Edge console I'm getting the error `SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0019, Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid.`

This seems to be a security certificate issue.

Comment: The certificate is expired since february 20. Which shouldn't happen in this case as it's from Let's Encrypt, which is meant to be set up with an automated way of certificate renewal. This automation seems to be broken for some reason.

Comment: And we finished the zbMath helper a while ago anyway.

Comment: Sorry --- I'll fix the certificate automation later today. Not sure what happened. I'll also contact Stack Exchange again about plugging in the new zbMath backend...

Comment: @Scott: Any news on the former task? It seems that the citation helper still fails to fetch results.

Comment: Let's Encrypt seems to have become broken on Amazon Linux, which is where we run the citation backend. I'm stuck for now, and am about to start escalating moving to our zbMath backend.

Comment: We've finally switched over to the zbMath backend, so this issue is now irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oded installed a new version of Scott Morrison's citation helper that uses an API to [Zentralblatt](https://zbmath.org/), which solved the problem. This change was already in the works, but I kept dropping the ball. Oded and Scott deserve the credit.

For the curious, I have [a SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/637434/which-posts-have-included-citations) that shows the 218 extant posts which have included citations. You might also be interested to know that Computational Science has also [started using the feature](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/470/add-insert-citation-button-to-editor-window) and has [four posts with citations](http://data.stackexchange.com/scicomp/query/637434/which-posts-have-included-citations).

Comment: Somewhat off topic _here_, but is there any chance of [math.se getting this, too](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/22008)?

Comment: Let me point out that there have been repeated requests that the feature will be implemented on [math.se] as well.

Comment: Is it just me, or is the citation helper *still* not working? I see exactly the behaviour described in the original post: a never ending cycle of three periods.

Comment: Though the root cause may be unrelated: the web console shows repeated (slowly) GET requests to zbmath interwoven with “TypeError: result.links[j].includes is not a function @ https://cdn.sstatic.net/js/third-party/citation-helper.js?v=ff4f467a0a2b:86”.