# Icon for citation helper

Tags: bug, status-completed, citation-helper

On the main MathOverflow site (and also on math.stackexchange) the icon for the [citation helper](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2583/new-feature-citation-helper), which used to look as below, has recently confusingly changed to a "B", identical to the icon at the far left for bold text. Could it be changed back, please?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that (although on math.SE) and was planning to make a post there.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Consider carrying out your plan regardless. I suspect the overworked staff is likely to notice a bug report on meta.math.SE earlier than here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Perhaps posting on Mathematics Meta (and later adding the status-review tag) would be good way to test the new way of escalating issues: [Community and Moderator guidelines for escalating issues via new response process (March 2020)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345032).

Comment: @Martin: I didn't see this, thanks. Unfortunately, it might be a couple of days before I get to do that. But if you want to raise this on meta.MSE, I'll be happy to add the status-review tag there...

Comment: A corresponding post on [math.meta.se]: [Button for citation helper in the editor](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31348).

Comment: Just an update, one of the StackOverlords has re-tagged the question on meta.MSE, which indicates we're on the radar for having this fixed.

Comment: And now is tagged [status-review] here, too, so the wheels are slooowly moving.

Comment: And now it is tagged status-completed here, so I guess the wheels have finished moving.