# The citation helper picks up a backlink to an MO answer when a DOI link is unavailable

Tags: bug, citation-helper

In the citation helper, I searched for "Lectures on the approach to Iwasawa theory for Hasse-Weil L-functions via BdR". The unique result that shows up is the following (I've only edited two occurrences of `\(...\)` to `$...$`; there is a separate [feature request](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5068) asking for this to be automated):

> *Kato, Kazuya*, [**Lectures on the approach to Iwasawa theory for Hasse-Weil $L$-functions via $B_{dR}$**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/6949), Colliot-Thélène, Jean-Louis et al., Arithmetic algebraic geometry. Lectures given at the 2nd session of the Centro Internazionale Matematico Estivo (C.I.M.E.), held in Trento, Italy, June 24 - July 2, 1991. Berlin: Springer-Verlag. Lect. Notes Math. 1553, 50-163 (1993). [ZBL0815.11051](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0815.11051).

The link over the title should be the DOI link to the paper: https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0084729. Instead, it points to a MathOverflow answer that has a link to the zbMATH review above.

In fact, the DOI of this paper is currently not indexed on its zbMATH review page. So, I presume that that is why the citation helper mistakenly picks up the link to the MathOverflow answer instead.

Comment: We are reworking some of the citation helper. Thanks for reporting, we'll look into that.

Comment: This happens to me repeatedly as well (usually pointing to works I have cited before; not sure if it is because I manually add DOI's). Some affected books are Fulton's *Intersection theory*, Hartshorne's *Algebraic geometry*, Neukirch's *Algebraic number theory*, Beauville's *Complex algebraic surfaces*, Katz's *Review of $\ell$-adic cohomology*, Goerss–Jardine's *Simplicial homotopy theory*, and (many authors') *FGA Explained*. These examples are all from the past three weeks.