# Can we publicise the brilliant "insert citation" button?

Tags: discussion, citations

This question is really just a heads up for the **insert citation** button. I'm a fairly regular user of MO, but I had no idea about this button until it was [mentioned by Joe Silverman in an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/224462/801).

I did a search on META and found a [really useful description of how the button works](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1485/formatting-citations-to-the-literature-on-mathoverflow). I did a little test run for myself and, goodness me, it's pretty fantastic.

I'm sure lots of people have seen the button but have not mentally registered. Perhaps if people agree that it's worth publicising, then they could vote this question up so that it's mentioned in the META box on the front page of MO. Alternatively, it would be great if one of the moderators could write a little post about the button, and make it a feature so it appears on the front page of MO.

Finally, I want to say "kudos to the developers". I imagine that implementing this feature took a deal of hard work, so credit where it's due -- great stuff!

Comment: There is a meta post form only a couple of days ago announcing it: [New feature - citation helper](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2583/new-feature-citation-helper) I vote to close this as duplicate. (One might consider "featuring" the other post though. Or, one might  consider the current phase as "beta" and make an extra post a bit later.) Maybe let me add that the button only is there since days. Earlier one needed to install a script and this was not an official feature.

Comment: @quid, thank you. I did search META before posting the question, but I missed the post you mention. Thanks for this -- closing is clearly the best thing to do.

Comment: No problem. Given the intent to publicize, some redundancy even seems desirable.